# Where to fetch user roles using ADFS service

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, adfs

I'm newbie to ADFS and I need to enable my web application developed with Spring Security to use ADFS service for user authentication and authorization, I've figured out the authentication process but it's the authorization piece is blocking me, actually, I'm confused, from where to get user roles? Because my datastore (mongoDB) neither have user info and roles which is required for securing my rest resources, can someone enlighten me how to implement same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ADFS wizard, you configure claims rules which place AD attributes in the token.

Some of these attributes can be roles which you can then use for authorisation.

That's assuming that there are some roles in the AD?

You can also use the claims rules to get attributes from your DB.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in my case I do not have roles in my db, so configuring ADFS seems to be only way in my case.